# Не работает glDrawElements

Tags: delphi, opengl

Вершины:

```
 var
      vertices: array[0..11] of GLfloat = (
        -0.5, 0.5, 0.0, // вершина 1
        -0.5, -0.5, 0.0, // вершина 2
        0.5, -0.5, 0.0, // вершина 3
        0.5, 0.5, 0.0 // вершина 4
        );
```

Индексы:

```
var
  indices: array[0..5] of GLushort = (
    0,1,3,
    1,2,3
    );
```

Добавляю массив вершин:

```
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, SizeOf(vertices), @vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
```

Отрисовка (Проблемный момент):

```
glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, Length(indices), GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, @indices);
```

Однако если вместо glDrawElements написать:

```
glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 6);
```

То что-то отрисуется, не то что надо конечно, но треугольники появятся, что указывает на работоспособность программы и какую-то ошибку в написании glDrawElements.
Вопрос заключается в том, как же всё-таки правильно использовать glDrawElements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы им неправильно пользуетесь.
Последний аргумент это указатель в массиве, а не вообще в памяти.
В вашем случае, правильно будет вот так:

```
glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, Length(indices), GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, Pointer(0));
```

---

Ссылка на доку (https://docs.gl/gl3/glDrawElements):

> void glDrawElements(  GLenum  mode, GLsizei   count, GLenum   type, const GLvoid *    indices);
>
> *indices* Specifies an offset of the first index in the array in the data store of the buffer currently bound to the GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER target.